# Hide URL when mouse hover over asp:HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have seen `javascript:void(0)` method used on `<a>` tags in HTML to hide the target URL of the hyperlinked object. Now I want to do the same on a `<asp:HyperLink>`, what should I do?

I am doing ASP.NET and here's the markup:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hl1">Blah blah blah</asp:HyperLink>
```

In the codebehind I specified the `NavigateUrl` for `hl1` using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` method.

---

I tried `hl1.Attributes[`href`]="javascript:void(0)";` in coebehind, does not work. Cannot open the `NavigateUrl` anymore.

Comment: Have you tried creating a method that gets triggered by your asp:hyperlink control? Why do you not want the user to see the URL? Kind of shady...

Comment: I am trying to create a JavaScript function to trigger the link.

Comment: You want to hide the url that shows at bottom of browser window?

Comment: Is it ok if the current page URL shows up at bottom of browser? By default a browser will display something.

Comment: @Sunil that could work. It can also be a message, a static string, anything.

Comment: Ok. Let me put the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the url you are wanting to navigate to in a hidden field and just set `NavigateUrl = "#"` in the markup as shown below. This way when user's cursor hovers over the link, the actual navigate URL will never be displayed at bottom of browser.

Then attach a `click` event handler on client-side for the hyperlink which you do by just setting `onclick` attribute of the hyperlink to a JavaScript function called `navigate`. The actual redirection to a new page is done by this `navigate` function.

In this situation, you will only see the URL of current page suffixed with `#`. For example, if your current page URL is `http://localhost/mysite/view.aspx` then it will show `http://localhost/mysite/view.aspx#` at bottom of browser.

**Markup needed**

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hl" NavigateUrl="#" 
           onclick="navigate();">Some Text</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnURL" runat="server" Value="http://www.microsoft.com" />
```

**JavaScript needed**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function navigate() {
            window.location.href = document.getElementById("<%=hdnURL.ClientID%>").value;
        }
</script>
```

**Another approach that you can use if you must set the NavigateURL for the hyperlink in code-behind** is as below. In this approach, you need to remove the NavigateURL before the content renders and store it in a global variable called `linkUrl`. The event that fires before the content renders is `pageLoad` and we will use that event to do this hack.

Global variable in JavaScript must always be declared outside all methods.

Then on clicking the hyperlink, we can obtain the value from the global variable of `linkUrl` and redirect user to that location.

*Note: Keep the markup of the hyperlink the same as in first approach. But remove the hidden field from that markup.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function navigate(event) {
         window.location.href = linkURL;
    }
    var linkUrl = null;
    function pageLoad() {
        var link = document.getElementById("<%=hl.ClientID%>");
        linkURL = link.getAttribute("href");
        link.setAttribute("href","#");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I will give you this one for my future reference. Thank you. But what I really need assigning `NavigateUrl` in the C# codebehind.

Comment: If you assign NavigateURL in code behind then you will end up with a`href="some url"` for the link, and then that URL would show at bottom when hovering the mouse over the link. So its necessary to instead set a hidden field's value with the url rather than NavigateURL.

Comment: There is a hack you can do if you must set the NavigateURL in code-behind, but do you want to hack it? If you want that hack I can post it also.

Comment: I get your point. However, the URL is not a static www.microsoft.com, it is generated based on a series of `if` statements.

Comment: Ok. I will post it now.

Comment: Added the other approach which you can use if you cannot escape setting the NavigateURL in code-behind.

Comment: If you have questions let me know.